# TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'fadeTo'

Tags: php, jquery, fadeto

I am trying to fade a div using this code:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function show(id) {
    //document.getElementsByName(id)[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementsByName(id)[0].fadeTo( "slow", 0.5 );
  }
  function hide(id) {
    document.getElementsByName(id)[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
  }


</script>
```

html:

```
<div style="width: 80px; height: 20px; background-color: red;" onmouseover="show('hej')" onmouseout="hide('hej')">
   <div id="div1" Name="hej" class="hej">Text</div>
</div>
```

I have included:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

And I get the error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'fadeTo' ".
Anyone who can help with fixing this and explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: `$('[name='+id=']').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript DOM elements do not have fadeTo method, you need to wrap it with jQuery

```
$(document.getElementsByName(id)[0])
```

or do this

```
$('[name="'+id+'"]').eq(0).fadeTo(
```

Comment: So $(document.getElementsByName(id)[0]).fadeTo( "slow", 0.5 ); ?

Comment: Hmm, it isn't working properly :/ try to look at http://gamestylerz.com/gameshop/ and then the red box

Answer (score 1):

Because you are targeting a DOM element and trying to call a jQuery method on it. You need to select the DOM object and put it in a jQuery collection:

```
function show(id) {
    $('[name='+id+']').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
}
function hide(id) {
    $('[name='+id+']').hide()
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jKJ9/)

I've assumed that since you are passing the name to the function, that it is unique, otherwise you'll want to make sure you only target the element within the current context. Something like this would work nicely for you:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jKJ9/2/)

Comment: You need to use .eq(0) to get the desired element incase there are more elements with the same name.

Comment: Or $(document.getElementsByName(id)[0]).fadeTo('slow', 0.5); - that would be equivalent too

Comment: what about `.get(0)`.

Comment: @Jai That will return the element and put us right back where we started.

Comment: @Anton True, except that this works, and the OP hasn't specified whether or not there will be more than one match for `[name=hej]`

Comment: .get(0) will return the DOM element, though you could use .first()

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is wrong :/ - you're trying to apply a jquery function to a javascript object.. which is why you're getting Object# error, instead of a JQuery Object error.
instead of getelementby id, use JQuery selectors.. have a look here:

http://blog.techplusone.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/jquery-Api-1.2.png
and book markit, it was a massive help to me before.

```
function show(id) {
   $('#' + id).show('slow');
  }
  function hide(id) {
     $('#' + id).hide('slow');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.fadeTo` is a method of a jquery object and `document.getElementsByName(id)` dont return a jquery object.

you can try:

```
$('[name="'+id+'"]').eq(0).fadeTo( "slow", 0.5 );
```